# calling on a stack inside a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, stack

i can't figure out why this part of my program won't work, I peek outside the while loop and confirm that the stack is not empty, yet when i try to access it inside the while loop I get this error:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException    at
>   java.util.Stack.peek(Unknown Source)"

here's the relevant piece of code

```
String test = list.peek();
    System.out.println(test);
    while(list.peek() != null)
    {
        temp = list.pop();
```

There's more too the while loop but it breaks once `list.peek` is called inside the parenthesis, I tried changing it to "`while(test != null)`" for test purposes but it breaks once it gets to `list.pop()`

Comment: `list.empty()` should do the job.

Comment: What is the declaration for `list`?

Comment: where would I use list.empty()? and the declaration is "public  Stack<String> list = new Stack<String>();"

Comment: The given error message indicates that `list` is a `Stack`.

Comment: take a look at my (and rgettman's) answers, they shows you how to use empty(). The idea is that for each iteration of your loop, you check if the stack is empty before the loop starts. That way you know the stack isn't empty inside the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `peek` method throws an `EmptyStackException` if the stack is empty.  To test if the stack is empty, use the [`empty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#empty%28%29) method:

```
while(!list.empty())
```

Also, don't name your `Stack` "list"; that can be confusing.

Answer (score 3):

When you `peek()`, that can also return a `EmptyStackException`. You should use this code instead:

```
while(!list.empty()) {
    temp = list.pop();
}
```

What's happening is that peek can't deal with an empty element the way you are assuming it can. You have to make sure the stack isn't empty before you `peek()`.

As a side note, it's a bit odd to name your Stack 'list'. That would imply your structure is a `List`